# How to avoid changing the Q-Factor when I wire additional resistors?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, rf

I used a tank circuit to make a RF transmitter at 107.302 MHz. My input voltage is 9V and current is 500 mA. I tested it with RF receiver, so everything works like a charm, but after all I noticed that the transistor is running at high level, which is not preferable in this case, and I know that this circuit is not an example for proper power transmission and is not suitable for any datasheets of electronics components. The fact that it would work for a short time means, that the components would heat themselves and the components would not work a correct way. It is only because the input should be sanitized by voltage regulator at the beginning of the circuit, so I can control and influence the current during the process.
What I need to know is, as you have seen in this circuit, the tank circuit (L1 and C2) and the R1 resistor makes this circuit oscillating with Q-factor of about 6.3, which is satisfying. But what if I want to control the voltage input from DC source, which has 9V and 500 mA, that is too much especially for Q1 transistor, would the parallel wired resistors I could and must add to the beginning of this circuit influence the Q-Factor of tank circuit? If yes, how can I avoid it?

[image: circuit]

[image: pic]

Comment: Personally I would use a simulator for testing out the ideas. At circa 100 MHz a simulator will be quite effective for RF circuits. Shouldn't there be a resistor in series with the power source V1?

Comment: I will search for that in search machine, how to debug it.(Q Factor). The resistor at the beginning would influence the Q-Factor, therefore the question.

Comment: I don't think it will oscillate without a resistor or impedance between V1 and the collector.

Comment: The resistor to oscillate is at the emitter of transistor and it works, as I predicted in my question.

Comment: I bet it actually works because of inherent inductance in series with your battery or power supply (due to wiring).

Comment: I mean wiring additional resistors, would decrease the Q-Factor here. The Q-Factor is already at 6.3 with resistor R1 of 10 ohm. It would go to zero, which will not oscillate at that frequency I mentioned before.

Comment: The problem I have is that I don't recognize your circuit as an oscillator and so, I would want to simulate it to see why it works but, as said, I suspect it may work because of parasitic components that a pure schematic doesn't reveal. Until we understand how it works, I for one can't recommend what to do.

Comment: The main thing in this circuit is the tank circuit, which has a resonant frequency.

Comment: It won't help trying to explain the circuit because I think it relies on parasitic values. A tank circuit on its own will not oscillate; it needs a feedback system and, I can't see how the transistor delivers this feedback system. That's why I suggest you simulate it.

Comment: It is simple a LCR circuit. The resistor at emitter is responsible for the Q-Factor.

Comment: I would suggest you try this if you want to reduce heat problems: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDTJQ.png

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same way to avoid heating of system. But the question was about how to avoid decreasing the Q-Factor in this circuit. That is the question.

Comment: I think the only way is increasing the inductor and decreasing the capacitor of tank circuit at the beginning of design to make Q-Factor bigger. After that, speculating about the resistors at DC source, so if the influence is there, no matter the Q-Factor will keep the resonant frequency alive.

Comment: Adding that resistor won't alter the Q-factor if I understand how the oscillator works (probably contrary to how you think it works).

Comment: Please reveal your component values and the transistor you used.

Comment: L1=0.1uH C2=22pF R1=R2=10ohm C3=4.7pF Q1=BC547B V1="9V 500mA" The transistor is not that much a good one, but for a short time it would do its job sufficiently.

Comment: OK I've simulated it and it doesn't oscillate. What makes your actual circuit oscillate is the way you have wired it up and, this makes it improbable to analyse and unlikely to be successfully analysed. This isn't how EEs design stuff. The simulator is telling me that your circuit is unreliable as an oscillator and likely will drift its operating frequency in an unpredictable way.

Comment: Thanks for researching and the simulation.